# Parent function return undefined in child component - angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

I am new in Angular 2 so please be lenient.

I want to use function (declared in parent component) in child component. I am using @output. This function should return some string, and child need to send this string to api.

So I have some parent function:

```
public ToJsonDate = (value: string) =>{

    try {
        let parts = value.split('-').map(Number);
        parts[1] -= 1;
        let date = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(null, parts));
        let textContent = '/Date(' + date.getTime() + '' + this.invoiceDataParent['temp'].Zone + ')/';
        console.log('test1', textContent);
        return textContent;
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }

}
```

and in HTML I've got:

```
div class="column2"><invoice [invoiceDataREST]='invoiceDataParent' (jsonDate)="ToJsonDate($event)"></invoice></div>
```

on child component I am using Output mechanism:

```
@Output() jsonDate: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

What i want to do is execute this function in another in child:

```
private sendInvoiceRequest() {
    this.isEdit = false;

    this.invoiceDataREST['ResponseDetails'].DocumentDate = this.jsonDate.emit(this.invoiceForm.controls['docDate'].value);
 console.log('test2',this.jsonDate.emit(this.invoiceForm.controls['docDate'].value);}
```

And now: 
test1 in console shows good output - so this function is executed for sure, but test 2 in console shows 'undefined'

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Output`  properties are not two-way.  They send data out, period.  There is no receiving an input through an output event emitter.  What you'll want to do is create an `Input` property as well that the parent function assigns the updated value to that goes *in* to the child component.  For example:

```
<div class="column2"><invoice [invoiceDataREST]='invoiceDataParent' (jsonDate)="ToJsonDate($event)"></invoice></div>

export class Parent{



    public ToJsonDate = (value: string) =>{

        try {
            let parts = value.split('-').map(Number);
            parts[1] -= 1;
            let date = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(null, parts));
            let textContent = '/Date(' + date.getTime() + '' + this.invoiceDataParent['temp'].Zone + ')/';
            console.log('test1', textContent);

            //assign new value to property that goes back into child component
            this.invoiceDataParent['ResponseDetails'].DocumentDate = textContent;
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }

    }

}



export class Child{
   @Input() invoiceDataREST: any;
   @Output() jsonDate: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

   private sendInvoiceRequest() {
    this.isEdit = false;

    this.jsonDate.emit(this.invoiceForm.controls['docDate'].value);
   }

}
```

I tried to update your code to show how this should work.  The `emit` does not retrieve the value from the parent.  It simply sends a value *out* to the parent.  The parent then will assign the value to the correct property on the object being sent *into* the child.

Hope this helps.